# (reversing)return to specified location in c , assembly

Tags: c, assembly, return, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I want to modify below c code and assembly code to pop up only one message box. 
The 'failed' message box pops up and then the 'success' message box pops up next now but I want to know the way of only the 'success' message box pops up after "Func" function is called.

I got a hint that the answer is related to "RET(assembly)" and I don't know how to modify not only the assembly code but also the c code. 
RET is the return address of previous function isn't it? Then how can I change this value in either side of code?

I know the RET is saved right before Func function is called so how can i do it??? pls someone help me with it!

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void Func(int n1, char ch) {
    int sum;
    sum = n1 + ch;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrev, LPSTR lpCmd, int nShow) {

    Func(10, 'A'); 

    MessageBox(0, "Failed", "", 0);
    MessageBox(0, "Success", "", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

compiled the c code and it looks like this in ollydbg.

```
// Func 
00401000  /$  55            PUSH EBP
00401001  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00401003  |.  51            PUSH ECX
00401004  |.  0FBE45 0C     MOVSX EAX,BYTE PTR SS:[EBP+C]
00401008  |.  8B4D 08       MOV ECX,DWORD PTR SS:[EBP+8]
0040100B  |.  03C8          ADD ECX,EAX
0040100D  |.  894D FC       MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-4],ECX
00401010  |.  8BE5          MOV ESP,EBP
00401012  |.  5D            POP EBP
00401013  \.  C3            RETN

// WinMain
00401014  /$  55            PUSH EBP
00401015  |.  8BEC          MOV EBP,ESP
00401017  |.  6A 41         PUSH 41                                  ; /Arg2 = 00000041
00401019  |.  6A 0A         PUSH 0A                                  ; |Arg1 = 0000000A
0040101B  |.  E8 E0FFFFFF   CALL test.00401000                       ; \test.00401000
00401020  |.  83C4 08       ADD ESP,8
00401023  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; /Style = MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL
00401025  |.  68 A0544000   PUSH test.004054A0                       ; |Title = ""
0040102A  |.  68 30504000   PUSH test.00405030                       ; |Text = "Failed"
0040102F  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; |hOwner = NULL
00401031  |.  FF15 94404000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&USER32.MessageBoxA>>; \MessageBoxA
00401037  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; /Style = MB_OK|MB_APPLMODAL
00401039  |.  68 A4544000   PUSH test.004054A4                       ; |Title = ""
0040103E  |.  68 38504000   PUSH test.00405038                       ; |Text = "Success"
00401043  |.  6A 00         PUSH 0                                   ; |hOwner = NULL
00401045  |.  FF15 94404000 CALL DWORD PTR DS:[<&USER32.MessageBoxA>>; \MessageBoxA
0040104B  |.  33C0          XOR EAX,EAX
0040104D  |.  5D            POP EBP
0040104E  \.  C2 1000       RETN 10
```

Are these __stdcall, __cdecl, __fastcall functions related with this question? 
or maybe the RETN argument?

Comment: Well, I don't use windows, but as a reverse engineer I know you could easily jump to the second message box. (eg. offset `00401023` you would change the hex from `6A 00` to `EB 11`... that should jump to offset`00401037`)

Comment: @l'L'l  and then how to make c code works same with it? I want to know the way of changing the return address in c code either to make same result.

Comment: @l'L'l Sorry that my question isn't clear :( I'm the beginner so I'm listening the lecture and the tutor recommends to solve this with not to delete the message box lol. I didn't mention up there. sorry for taking your time!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly - you need to modify your C code to make one `MessageBox` call disappear, without removing a call from the source code. Most easiest way will be modifying a function return address to jump directly to the second `MessageBox`. Lets illustrate this approach with the simple example.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(){}

int main(void)
{
    test();

    printf("%s\n", "test1");
    printf("%s\n", "test2");

    return(0);
}
```

Disassembly (relevant) of the `main` function:
[image]

Return address from the `test` function will be `011B17F3`. If we want to skip first `printf` call, we want it to be `011B1805` instead. So it has to be increased by `0x12`.

To do that, we have to retrieve saved return address from the stack, increase it, and then write it back.

```
void test()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov eax, [ebp+4]
        add eax, 0x12
        mov [ebp+4], eax
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I had no idea the __asm function is existed and how to use it! Thank you so much and can I ask one more question? Is it possible to jmp to `011B1805` to use `RET` in assembly code? like.. `RET ARGUMENT or something`. I'm sorry with my low quality question. I'm the beginner one. Thanks a lot !!!! :)

Comment: No. Ret uses an address, saved on stack.

Comment: I get it. I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: This is very scary and may not work on other compilers or if optimization is switched on.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Of course) Entire idea reeks of trouble. I believe all of this is needed only to study reverse engineering.

Comment: why not set a label and simply use goto label ? in the source code